# Create 3D illusion for a dark button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this button right now:

```css
.audio-controls {
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1226px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 82%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.audio-controls .record {
  zoom: 0.042;
  transform: translate(0px, 40px);
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

.prompt {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.prompt .stim {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 124px;
  width: 126px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  background: linear-gradient(#2a292b, #111013);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px #000;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stim p {
  color: #b9b7b7;
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  font-size: .7em;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  transition: color 0.1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.prompt .stim i {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}

.prompt .stim::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/carbon-fibre.png);
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/ps-neutral.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-controls">
  <div id="start-recognition" class="prompt">
    <div class="stim">
      <svg class="record" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve" style="fill: rgb(123, 55, 32);" width="1000" height="1000">
        <rect id="backgroundrect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke="none" />
        <g class="currentLayer" style="">
          <g id="svg_1" class="selected" fill="#dadada" fill-opacity="1">
            <path d="M500,683.8c84.6,0,153.1-68.6,153.1-153.1V163.1C653.1,78.6,584.6,10,500,10c-84.6,0-153.1,68.6-153.1,153.1v367.5C346.9,615.2,415.4,683.8,500,683.8z M714.4,438.8v91.9C714.4,649,618.4,745,500,745c-118.4,0-214.4-96-214.4-214.4v-91.9h-61.3v91.9c0,141.9,107.2,258.7,245,273.9v124.2H346.9V990h306.3v-61.3H530.6V804.5c137.8-15.2,245-132.1,245-273.9v-91.9H714.4z" id="record-icon" fill="#dadada57" />
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <p>Hold Space Key</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add a 3d effect of clicking like this button at the bottom of my button like this:

[image]

The issue is I'm unable to add that shadowing so that it seems realistic no matter how good I try!

How can I create such a great illusion?

Here is the code for above image :

https://cssdeck.com/labs/large-pressable-css-button#

Comment: You need to use `box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #c5376d, 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.prompt .stim {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 124px;
  width: 126px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background: linear-gradient(#2a292b, #111013);
  background-color: #111013;  /* added */
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #000;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

this is very similar to the answer Azu gave, except I've also added a solid background colour, which is applied underneath and stops that weird line where the page peaks through your element.

hope it helped :)